# FileNotFoundError for a json file on hdfs location when running oozie

Tags: json, arguments, workflow, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to pass a dictionary of arguments to a script (a spark action) in an oozie.
The dictionary is in a .json file.
I pass the .json file as an argument in workflow.xml  but deploying the coordinator of my oozie I get the file not found error (as below)

[image: Error in oozie]

I can see the file in the hdfs location though
[image: files at the hdfs location]

This is how I am including the .json file in the argument in my workflow.xml
[image: .json file in workflow.xml]

Comment: Can you please share the code as to how you are reading this file in your python program?

Comment: I found a way to add this  as simply the file name and adding a --files option above